# How to pass a JSON object to web2py using JQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, web2py

I've used [this method](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) in .NET to pass data back and forth between client and server using JSON objects (both ways).   I really liked the method and am looking to do something similar with web2py.  Web2py supports returning json objects and supports jsonrpc.  I haven't however been able to make it parse a JSON object.   My client call looks like this:

```
var testObject = {};
testObject.value1 = "value1value!";
testObject.value2 = "value2value!";

var DTO = { 'testObject' : testObject };
var data = $.toJSON(DTO);    //Using the toJSON plugin by Mark Gibson

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MyWeb2PyApp/MyController/jsontest.json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
success:  function(data){  alert('yay'); }
});
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff in my jsontest action and nothing works.

Has anyone been able to accomplish something similar?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are multiple ways. In your case the simplest thing to do is

```
def jsontest():
   import gluon.contrib.simplejson
   data = gluon.contrib.simplejson.loads(request.body.read())
   return dict()
```