# Send object from view to function controller in Web2py

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web2py

I trying to send un object from a view to controller (Web2py) in the same way that:

[How to pass a JSON object to web2py using JQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719244/how-to-pass-a-json-object-to-web2py-using-jquery-ajax)

The ajax part is:

```
var testObject = {};
testObject.value1 = "value1value!";
testObject.value2 = "value2value!";

var DTO = { 'testObject' : testObject };

var data = $.toJSON(DTO);    //Using the toJSON plugin by Mark Gibson

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Myapplication/controllers/jsontest.json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
success:  function(data){  alert('yay'); }
});
```

and the function jsontest is in /Myapplication/controllers/default.py I have

```
def jsontest():
   import gluon.contrib.simplejson
   data = gluon.contrib.simplejson.loads(request.body.read())
   return dict()
```

Doing the same test I got a good string  in `var data = $.toJSON(DTO);`   .I got the json.js in  https://sites.google.com/site/jollytoad/json.js?attredirects=0

but nothing is transmited to the jsontest function. Can anyone explain me what is wrong? I thing my url could be bad ... etc  Thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: '/Myapplication/controllers/jsontest.json'
```

The above is not a valid web2py URL ("controllers" is the name of the folder that holds the controller files, but it does not appear in the URL). The correct URL would be:

```
url: '/Myapplication/default/jsontest.json'
```

If the Javascript is in a web2py view file (rather than a separate .js file), then the preferred way to generate the URL is via the `URL()` function:

```
url: '{{=URL('default', 'jsontest.json')}}'
```

For more details, see the book sections on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Dispatching) and the [`URL()` function](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#URL).

Note, your code assumes either the existence of a /views/default/jsontest.json view file or that you have enabled the generic.json view (see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#Generic-views) for more details). However, the jsontest() function doesn't actually return anything to the view or do anything with the JSON data.

Comment: hi thanks, now the url is correct. I have added in jsontext  the next code after data:myfile = os.path.join(request.folder, 'static', 'file.txt')
   f = open(myfile, "w")       
   f.write(data)
   f.close(). The file.txt is created but nothing is writing inside the file... Do you have an explanation?